# can't do imagejpeg() for multiple images

Tags: php

I have this code and I need to make this work:

```
         if ($handle = opendir("images/")) { $i=0;
                   while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
                    if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file != "Recursive Dir_Renfiles_dirname-filename.php") {
                        $filename[$i]=$file;
                        $i++;
                    }}}
                    //print_r($filename);

foreach($filename as $filename){
    $percent = 0.5;

    // Content type
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

    // Get new dimensions
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
    $new_width = $width * $percent;
    $new_height = $height * $percent;

    // Resample    
    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

    // Output
    imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);    
}
```

I there a way to make this work? Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Try to describe at least what the problem is. ('This chunk of code doesn't work' is not a description).

Comment: `imagejpeg()` outputs the image. You cannot generate multiple output. What are you trying to do exactly? Are you trying to mix these images together?

Comment: Yes - Our question would be - What isn't working exactly?  For all we know, you may not have permissions to write these files - which would not be something we could tell by looking at the code.

Comment: Oh, sorry. The problem is that imagejpeg works only if I give him one image. If I give array it stops. I tried with while loop, for, foreach and nothing gives result.

Comment: I'm trying to do this for each image in this folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want multiple images on one page, you should use this PHP file to produce one image, and then use the PHP file as the source in an HTML image tag, like this:

```
<img src="picture.php?img_id=1" />
<img src="picture.php?img_id=2" />
```

---

**NOTE:**

When getting the filename via `$_GET`, it would be a good idea to watch out for unexpected characters, especially slashes. Someone could call the URL like this: `picture.php?filename=../badImage.jpg`, which may display a file in a different folder than you want them to have access to. So perhaps do something like `$_GET["filename"] = stripslashes($_GET["filename"]);` or something.

Comment: ok. So, I could,instead of this,pass image to this page(<img src="picture.php?picture=$filename" />
),and then this will work for all images?

Comment: Yes. Your PHP file will only display one image at a time, but your HTML code will use the same PHP file as the source for multiple different images. You just need to pass in the filename or image ID or something to get the PHP script to pull up one specific image.

Comment: So instead of using `$filename` in your PHP script, you'll get the filename via `$_GET["filename"]`.

Comment: Thanks,this works!I only need to define height and width and that's it!

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please see my updated answer for something you should probably watch out for.